# IE changes elements arrangement based on their content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

If span content contains *dots in the begining* `<span>.filename</span>` then Internet Explorer won't reflow them.

How to make IE reflow spans without the need to remove the dots?

[JS Fiddle demo: with dots in content](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZQZB/1/) - use IE
[JS Fiddle demo: without dots](http://jsfiddle.net/UrNCv/)

P.S.  If `<span>` changed to `<li>` problem remain.

Comment: you could add this to the parent `div {word-wrap:break-word;}`

Comment: This is a new one for me, bizarre behavior. You'll probably have to change the display type of the spans.

Comment: Just for reference, I've confirmed this behaviour across all IE versions from IE8 through to IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. This does look wrong.

A quick solution would be to change the display type of your `span` elements to `inline-block`.

In your fiddle, add:

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

...in the CSS panel. This will make IE work as expected. See [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZQZB/10/).

It doesn't actually fix the issue; it just works around it, but it does solve the problem as far as your fiddle is concerned.

Hopefully it'll work for you in your actual site as well (it should do, but obviously depends on your page layout; `inline` and `inline-block` do work differently, so it is possible there could be some odd edge cases).

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why IE behaves in that way, but In your case you can try go with

```
span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: +1 because you got the same answer as I did at the same time. I've also got no idea why IE is doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to achieve it:
Include `display:inline-block` in your div and then apply css to your span tag by inheriting from your div.

Example:

```
<div style="background-color:black;display:inline-block;"> 

span {
  display:inherit;     
}
```